# Telium Adventure Game: how to fix the problem where it prints out any npc's in the room but instead it just prints there is 'None' here

Tags: python

There is module files as well but they work perfectly, the main problem is when you enter a module and it just printing out There is 'none' in here for every module. Additionally, if I wanted to change the fuel gain from 50 to randomly chose between 20,30,40 or 50.

The rest of the code works well but when the npc in a room is outputted it should say there is a 'workers' in here instead of just none for each module.

```
#Telium - Game

import random

#Global Variables

num_modules = 17          #Number of modules in the space station
module = 1                #Module of space station we are in
last_module = 0           #Last module we were in
possible_moves = []       #List of possible moves we can make
alive = True              #Whether player is alive or not
won = False               #Whether player has won
power = 100               #Amount of power the space station has
fuel = 500                #Amount of fuel the player has in flamethrower
locked = 0                #Module that has been locked by the player
queen = 0                 #Location of queen alien
vent_shafts = []          #Location of ventilation shaft entrances
info_panels = []          #Location of info panels
workers = []              #Location of worker aliens

#procedure declarations
#This loads the global module 
def load_module():
    global module, possible_moves
    possible_moves = get_modules_from(module)
    output_module()

def get_modules_from(module):
    moves = []
    text_file = open("Charles_Darwin\module" + str(module) + ".txt", "r")
    for counter in range(0,4):
        move_read = text_file.readline()
        move_read = int(move_read.strip())   
        if move_read != 0:
            moves.append(move_read)
    text_file.close()
    return moves

def output_module():
    global module    
    print()
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------- 
-----------------------")
    print()
    print("You are in module",module)
    print()
    npc = spawn_npcs()

    print("There is a ", npc ,"here")

def output_moves():
    global possible_moves
    print()
    print("From here you can move to modules: | ",end='') 
    for move in possible_moves:
        print(move,'| ',end='')
    print()

def get_action():
    global module, last_module, possible_moves, power
    valid_action = False
    while valid_action == False:
        print("What do you want to do next ? (MOVE, SCANNER)")
        action = input(">")
        if action == "MOVE" or action.lower() == 'move' or action.lower() 
== 'm' or  action.higher() == 'M':
            move = int(input("Enter the module to move to: "))
            if move in possible_moves:
                valid_action = True
                last_module = module
                module = move
                #power is decreased by 1 for every move
                power =- 1
            else:
                print("The module must be connected to the current 
module.")

def spawn_npcs():
    global num_modules, queen, vent_shaft, greedy_info_panels, workers
    module_set = []
    for counter in range(2,num_modules):
        module_set.append(counter)
    random.shuffle(module_set)
    i = 0
    queen = module_set[i]
    for counter in range(0,3):
        i=i+1
        vent_shafts.append(module_set[i])

    for counter in range(0,2):
        i=i+1
        info_panels.append(module_set[i])

    for counter in range(0,3):
        i=i+1
        workers.append(module_set[i])
    
def check_vent_shafts():
    global num_modules, module, vent_shafts, fuel
    if module in vent_shafts:
        print("There is a bank of fuel cells here.")
        print("You load one into your flamethrower.")
        fuel_gained = 50
        print("Fuel was",fuel,"now reading:",fuel+fuel_gained)
        fuel = fuel + fuel_gained
        print("The doors suddenly lock shut.")
        print("What is happening to the station?")
        print("Our only escape is to climb into the ventilation shaft.")
        print("We have no idea where we are going.")
        print("We follow the passages and find ourselves sliding down.")
        last_module = module
        module = random.randint(1,num_modules)
        load_module()
    
#Main Program starts here
#Menu options
 
print("ENTER 1 for instructions")
print("ENTER 2 to play")
print("ENTER 3 to quit")

menu = int(input("Please enter a number corresponding to what you want to 
do: "))
if menu == 1:
    instructions = input("Do you want to read the instructions(Y/N): ")
    if instructions == "Y":
        print("You, the player are trying to navigate around a space 
station named the 'Charles Darwin' which contains many modules")
        print("The aim of the game is to find a and trap the queen alien 
called 'Telium' who is located somewhere randomly in the station, the 
queen will try to escape to connectinhg modules so beware")
        print("To win - you have to lock the queen in one of the modules 
so she is trapped, you can kill her with a flamethrower, there is also 
objects to help on the way so keep a look out")

spawn_npcs()
#Outputs where the queen, shafts, panels and workers are located
print("Queen alien is located in module:",queen)
print("Ventilation shafts are located in modules:",vent_shafts)
print("Information panels are located in modules:",info_panels)
print("Worker aliens are located in modules:",workers)


#when the players is alive, the module will load 
while alive and not won:
    load_module()
    if won == False and alive == True:
        output_moves()
        get_action()
#if power is 0 then the user will die and the game will end
    if power == 0:
        print("You ran out of life support, you died")
        alive == False

#win message once you have trapped the queen or when you run out of life 
support
if won == True:
    print("The queen is trapped and you burn it to death with your 
flamethrower.")
    print("Game over. You win!")
if alive == False:
    print("The station has run out of power. Unable to sustain life 
support, you die.")

check_vent_shafts()
```

Comment: You have `npc = spawn_npcs()`, and then you print `npc` via `print("There is a ", npc ,"here")`, but `spawn_npcs` doesn't return anything. Any function that doesn't explicitly return anything automatically returns `None`, which is why `npc` is `None`. It's not clear exactly what you are expecting to be returned from `spawn_npcs`. There's nothing in your code that would output `'workers'` when printed (that I can see).

Comment: @RandomDavis the spawn_npcs() function is below the main program so would the print message need to be below that function and in the main section?

Comment: I'm not following what you're saying. I'm talking about just what's going on within the `output_module()` function. The order of where the function `spawn_npcs` is defined has nothing to do with this issue. The issue is that there's no code that prints or returns "workers" at all, and also that you're printing the return value of a function that does not return anything. I see that you call `spawn_npcs` once in the main program as well, but that's irrelevant from what I can see. What you say you want your code to do, versus what it is doing, doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @RandomDavis I'm not very good at coding so I don't really know what to do but it's supposed to randomly assign the different npcs in to random nodules which is done before the main program starts like where it says 'workers.append(module_set[I])

Comment: Okay so what do you want to print and under what criteria should it be printed?

Answer (score 0):

First the easy part. You can randomly get 20, 30, 40 or 50 by using `random.randint` like this:

```py
random.randint(2, 5) * 10
```

The harder part:

As you discussed with @Random Davis in the comments, you want to assign the npcs to random modules and then print which one you encounter.

To append three random (possibly repeating) modules, use

```
for _ in range(0,3):
    vent_shafts.append(random.choice(module_set))
```

Using global variables (and the global keyword) is generally considered bad practice as it can cause sideeffects due to other parts of the program modifying a variable you wouldn't expect it to / forgot about. Try to use them as function parameters where needed and return the results

```py
queen, vent_shafts, info_panels, workers = spawn_npcs(5)
def spawn_npcs(num_modules):

    module_set = []
    for i in range(2, num_modules):
        module_set.append(i)

    for _ in range(0,3):
        vent_shafts.append(random.choice(module_set))

    for _ in range(0,2):
        info_panels.append(random.choice(module_set))

    for _ in range(0,3):
        workers.append(random.choice(module_set))

    queen_module = module_set[0]

    return queen_module, vent_shafts, info_panels, workers
```